# Powershell script:how to Filter on AD Get commands to return certain information

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script that checks AD group membership/domain/manage by etc amongst other information and puts into csv file, because I want to structure the csv file in a certain way how do i filter within the actual script to only return certain information e.g. withe the code below its returning a lot more columns but from these the only ones i want are "managed by" and "name":

```
Get-ADDomain -property managed By, Name|Export-csv -path C:\AD\Domain.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-Properties` to specify the properties you want, and then pipe to `Select-Object` to select the properties you want in the output. For example:

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties canonicalName,userPrincipalName |
  select-object canonicalName,userPrincipalName |
  export-csv myfile.csv -notypeinformation
```

Get-ADDomain doesn't have `-Properties` but you can still use `Select-Object`:

```
get-addomain | select-object ManagedBy,Name | export-csv myfile.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: I understand now that part but when I amend it to my requirements I get the error " A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'properties"

Comment: Thats has worked thank you, you mentioned get-addomain doesnt have properties, would the best approach to gather specific information in AD be to use your approach of select-object..because I have a few Get commands I need to run to produce certain AD information in a specific order within a csv file.